# How to test Google maps info window contents using Espresso / UI Automator?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-espresso, android-testing, android-uiautomator

How to test Google map marker's info window contents for automation testing using Espresso or UI Automator.

I click on the map's marker using ui-automator like this...

```
val device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation())
val marker = device.findObject(UiSelector().descriptionContains(markerTitle))

if (marker.exists()) {
    marker.click()
}
```

i tried checking the info window contents with both espresso and UI-automator but unfortunately they are not working. is there any other way to test this.

Thanks!